# jquery selective display of form inputs based on selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, dropdown, forms

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  return $("body").on("change",".creator_name_type", function(event){
    if (event.target.value == 'Personal') {
      $(this).siblings(".organization_name").hide();
      $(this).siblings(".given_name").show();
      $(this).siblings(".family_name").show();
    } else {
      $(this).siblings(".given_name").hide();
      $(this).siblings(".family_name").hide();
      $(this).siblings(".organization_name").show();
    }
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function(){
   return $("body").on("click", ".add_creator", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var creatorClass = $(this).attr('data-addCreator');
  var cloneUbiDiv = $(this).parent('div' + `${creatorClass}`).clone();
  $(`${creatorClass}` +  ':last').after(cloneUbiDiv);
        
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="creator">
     <select class="creator_name_type">
      <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
     <option value="Organisational">Organisational</option>
    </select>
      given name: <input type="text" name="gname" class="given_name"><br>
      family name: <input type="text" name="fname" class="family_name"><br>
      organization name: <input type="text" name="oname" class"organization_name"><br>

  <a href="#" class=" add_creator" data-addCreator=".creator">Add another </a>

   <div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to selectively display form input based on selected options. The form has buttons for **add more** which just clones and append the cloned html to the bottom of the div. When I click **add more** and now have 2 select tags with one having the selected value as 'Personal' and the other a selected value of "organization". Rather than selectively show the form fields based on the if/else statement, it shows thesame form fields for both while retaining different selected value for each dropdown  options ie one dropdown shows personal as selected and the other shows Organization. Everytime the on change event fires for one of them, thesame form fields are displayed for both rather than displaying form fields based on the if/else statement.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  return $("body").on("change",".creator_name_type", function(event){
    if (event.target.value == 'Personal') {
      $(".organization_name").hide();
      $(".given_name").show();
      $(".family_name").show();
    } else {
      $(".given_name").hide();
      $(".family_name").hide();
      $(".organization_name").show();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Sir...not reproducible. Reproducible example please.

Comment: Sir it is now reproducible. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you are doing your show/hide based on class (e.g. `.given_name`) and all the similar form fields will have the same class, so they all change together. Try using [`.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find the appropriate fields to show/hide. You also have a typo in the option value, it is `"personal"`, not `"Personal"`, and you are missing an `"="` in the input with class `organization_name`. Here's a working snippet:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  return $("body").on("change",".creator_name_type", function(event){
    if (event.target.value == 'personal') {
      $(this).siblings(".organization_name").hide();
      $(this).siblings(".given_name").show();
      $(this).siblings(".family_name").show();
    } else {
      $(this).siblings(".given_name").hide();
      $(this).siblings(".family_name").hide();
      $(this).siblings(".organization_name").show();
    }
  });
});

 $(document).ready(function(){
   return $("body").on("click", ".add_creator", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var creatorClass = $(this).attr('data-addCreator');
  var cloneUbiDiv = $(this).parent('div' + `${creatorClass}`).clone();
  $(`${creatorClass}` +  ':last').after(cloneUbiDiv);
    
});
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="creator">
     <select class="creator_name_type">
      <option value="personal">Personal</option>
     <option value="organisational">Organisational</option>
    </select>
      given name: <input type="text" name="gname" class="given_name"><br>
      family name: <input type="text" name="fname" class="family_name"><br>
      organization name: <input type="text" name="oname" class="organization_name"><br>

  <a href="#" class=" add_creator" data-addCreator=".creator">Add another </a>

   <div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and though the change event is triggered the fields dont' hide or show, meaning they remain on changed using the suggested approach. I modified it to use parent as in **$(this).parent(".creator_organization_name").show()** still nothing change is triggered but nothing is hidden, the fields displayed just remain unchnage.

Comment: If you could post the relevant part of the HTML that would make it easier to debug...

Comment: When I open developer tools and do $('.creator_name_type').closest(".organization_name").length, I get zero. However, if I do $(".organization_name").length, I get 4

Comment: Just added some minimal code to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Based on your sample HTML, `siblings` is the appropriate property to use, not `closest`. I note in the sample HTML you have `<option value="personal">`, I presume that's a typo and it should be `<option value="Personal">` otherwise the if won't work. Anyway I've edited my answer and I think you'll find that works...

Comment: Is it working now? I've updated my answer with a working code snippet based on yours.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad we got there in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In your above code personal's value doesn't match with Personal i.e. you need to have personal's p in small letter.b That's why values are not matching

Instead of this " if (event.target.value == 'Personal') {"

write this "if (event.target.value == 'personal') {"

Comment: Thanks for helping but even after changing it, that did not solve the problem,

Comment: I tried it on js fiddler . its working there. attaching the fiddler link here [link]https://jsfiddle.net/6o7yvc89/10/

Comment: Also replace line " organization name: <input type="text" name="oname" class"organization_name"><br>" with this:   "organization name: <input type="text" name="oname" class = "organization_name"><br>"

Comment: many thanks for the fidldler and other suggestions. Nick got it working earlier on.